# Why the code is reaching Exception block?

Tags: python, exception

```
x=int(input("Enter the Dividend:"))
y=int(input("Enter the Divisor:"))
try:
    ans=x/y
    print('Answer:'+ans)
except:
    print("Cannot divide it by zero!!!")
```

```
Enter the Dividend:12
Enter the Divisor:3
Cannot divide it by zero
```

Comment: _Inspect_ your exception, don't just catch everything and assume it's the specific error you think it is.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Don't spoil the surprise!

Comment: @BodhisattwaDas There's no problem with your indentation.

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate..Solved the issue with your inputs

Answer (score 2):

Your error is that you forgot to convert your answer to string while concatenating it to your print statement, resulting in an error that was caught by your bare exception. The comments about bare excepts are totally correct, so I changed it to be a ZeroDivisionError

```py
x=int(input("Enter the Dividend:"))
y=int(input("Enter the Divisor:"))
print(x)
print(y)
try:
    ans = x/y
    print('Answer:'+str(ans))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Cannot divide it by zero!!!")
```

Answer (score 2):

Fire up the shell and experiment

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = 100
>>> y = 20
>>> ans = x/y
>>> 'Answer:'+ans
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Looks like you got a type error because `Answer:'+ans` doesn't work. That's the problem with a generic exception block, it makes it hard to detect other errors.

This fixes the problem

```
x=int(input("Enter the Dividend:"))
y=int(input("Enter the Divisor:"))
try:
    ans=x/y
    print('Answer: {}'.format(ans))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Cannot divide it by zero!!!")
```